# Trouble getting Response Compression working for .js files in ASP.NET Core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, gzip

I've configured my application following these instructions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/response-compression?tabs=aspnetcore2x.

I want the defaults (Gzip, Fastest, etc.) so I simply modified by `Startup.cs` with:

`services.AddResponseCompression()` in `ConfigureServices()` and `app.UseResponseCompression()` immediately before `app.UseMvc()` in `Configure()`.

This appears to work for the html reponse:

[image]

But not for my static JavaScript files, which are more of a concern:

[image]

According to the documentation `application/javascript` is specified as a default MIME type for compression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ... and app.UseResponseCompression() immediately before app.UseMvc()
>   in Configure()

JavaScript files are served by static files middleware, that's why you should add compression middleware before middleware for static files. Here is a correct sequence for `Configure` method:

```
app.UseResponseCompression();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

[image]